# Chrome.storage sync across tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can you save a variable using `chrome.storage.sync` and have it persist across tabs?

I'd like a user to set their name once and then have that set forever. However, when a user opens a new tab the new tab cannot access the name variable set with

```
// set 
chrome.storage.sync.set({'name': name});

// get
chrome.storage.sync.get(['name'])
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) it appears that the behavior should be similar to localStorage and work across tabs

Do you need to sync the storage when a new tab is loaded?

Comment: Were you able to make it work with `local`?

Comment: @DanielMöller yeh, same behavior

Answer (score -2):

Get is an asynchronous function, you must have a callback to access the value:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['name'], function(result){
    if ('name' in result)
    {
         console.log(result['name']);
    }
});
```

Set is also an asynchronous function! You won't get anything if you do both in sequence.

Comment: was an issue somewhere else in the code, thanks for the help thought :)